Are van der Waals forces the same thing as intermolecular forces?
Like the name suggests, intermolecular forces are those between molecules and can be forces of attraction between permanent dipoles or temporary dipoles. However, it seems that the definition of van der Waals forces is slightly ambiguous, with various sources giving me various definitions.
Are van der Waals forces the same thing? Or are they a subset of intermolecular forces that don't include a particular type of intermolecular force like the Keesom interaction? Or does it depend on the context?
I am looking for a definite answer to what the difference is between van der Waals forces and intermolecular forces or if they really are the same thing?

van der Waals force is a thing, van der Waals is a family name.

CH SE site is not the authoritative source of definitions. The IUPAC Goldbook is.

There are lots of similar posts on the site: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=van+der+waals+forces
